# I get a Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement when i run this code

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2010

Hi my code is throwing an exception and the error message is Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement: I need help in identifying the error in statement, i have searched for it and cant seem to identify

```
  Dim sSql As String = "INSERT INTO MEMBERS ([MID], [NAME], [SURNAME], [GENDER], [PHONE], [ADDRESS]," _
                                           & "[STATUS], [JOB], [DOB], [TITLE], [INITIALS], [AGE], [FOTO], [2MID], [RELATE]" _
                                           & " [2#], [2NOTES], [DOBa], [POB], [BO], [LRs], [AD], [AOID], [MNOTES], [LAN], [AP])" _
                                           & "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) "
                    ' Dim MEM As String = "INSERT INTO MEMBERS (MID, SURNAME, ADDRESS)" & "VALUES(?,?,?)"



                    Dim save As New OleDbCommand(sSql, DC)
                    save.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txtID.Text)
                    save.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txtName.Text)
                    save.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txtSName.Text)
                    save.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", Gender.Text)
                    save.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", Phone.Text)
                    save.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txtAdd.Text)
                    save.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", Status.Text)
                    save.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", Work.Text)
                    save.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", dtpDOB.Text)
                    save.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", cmbT.Text)
                    save.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txtIT.Text)
                    save.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", Age.Text)
                    save.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarBinary).Value = stream.GetBuffer()
                    save.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txtNoKID.Text)
                    save.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txtR.Text)
                    save.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txtRNs.Text)
                    save.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txt2N.Text)
                    save.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", dtpDOBa.Text)
                    save.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txtPOB.Text)
                    save.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txtBO.Text)
                    save.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txtLRs.Text)
                    save.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", dtpAD.Text)
                    save.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txtAOID.Text)
                    save.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", rtbMNotes.Text)
                    save.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txtLAN.Text)
                    save.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txtAP.Text)
                    save.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txtID.Text)
                    save.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    DC.Close()
                End Using
            End Using
            'Catch ex As Exception
            'MsgBox(ex.Message)
            'End Try

        End If
```

Comment: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a comma after `[RELATE]`.

Also consider using named parameters instead of anonymous parameters.